# Basic Variable Lookup in R

Tags: r

I have two files. One has a series of genes that I'm interested in. The other has genes and their pathways they are associated with. So the first list looks like this:

```
Solyc08g062250
Solyc02g069270
Solyc07g064990
Solyc09g065800
Solyc02g077620
Solyc01g104400
Solyc02g065290
Solyc02g090220
```

and another list with these genes and what "pathways" they belong to (this is a sample of the file, the file is much larger and has several pathways and genes):

```
Solyc10g008120  1,3,5-trimethoxybenzene biosynthesis
Solyc02g069920  1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I
Solyc04g005180  1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I
Solyc04g005190  1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I
Solyc04g005200  1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I
Solyc05g005180  1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I
Solyc06g071030  1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I
```

The catch is that several of my genes fall into several pathways. I need a good way to get each gene and have all of the pathways it is in charge of listed next to each gene ID that I input from a set.

I was originally trying to use the command

```
c<-b[b$GeneID %in% a$GeneIDs,]
```

where b was my pathway/GeneID and a was my list of Gene IDs that I wanted, but it only returns one pathway and I know a number of these genes fall into several pathways.

I'm new to programming entirely so I've been having trouble with this. Any help would be appreciated! I don't know how to search on Internet because I don't know what this is called.

Comment: You can look through the GeneID of the first one using `lapply` and then do `%in%`. i.e. `lapply(a$GeneIDs, function(x) b[b$GeneID ==x,])`  The output will be a list of `data.frames` (assuming that is what you wanted)

Comment: This question is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331830/r-find-frequencies-over-3rd-quartile-in-table you may want to give the accepted answer a try

Comment: please keep in mind that `c` is itself a function in R, and assigning variables to `c` might cause odd behavior

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If so, please consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark below the question votes

Comment: Gimme some time PavoDive, I just woke up right now. I'll give the answers a try as I read down the list and understand the commands. I'm new at this so I need to look up the commands and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help, using some toy data:

```
allgenes <- c("a", "b", "c")
dat <- data.frame(gene = c(rep("a", 2), "b", rep("c", 2)), 
   path = paste("path", 1:5))
dat
 gene   path
1    a path 1
2    a path 2
3    b path 3
4    c path 4
5    c path 5
```

Create a data frame with commas separating each path

```
res <- lapply(allgenes, function(y) paste(dat$path[which(dat$gene %in% y)], collapse=", "))
data.frame(allgenes, paths=do.call(rbind, res))

  allgenes          paths
1        a path 1, path 2
2        b         path 3
3        c path 4, path 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to do something like this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

gene.interested =
  data_frame(gene = c(
    "Solyc10g008120",
    "Solyc02g069920",
    "Solyc08g062250"))

gene__pathway =
  data_frame(
    gene = c(
      "Solyc10g008120",
      "Solyc02g069920",
      "Solyc02g069920",
      "Solyc04g005180"),
    pathway = c(
      "1,3,5-trimethoxybenzene biosynthesis",
      "1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I",
      "1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I",
      "1,4-dihydroxy-2-naphthoate biosynthesis I"))

result = 
  gene.interested %>%
  left_join(gene__pathway) %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  summarize(pathways = pathway %>% paste(collapse = "; "))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand what you are trying to do:
(1) Loop through each gene in the first file, 
(2) Find all of pathways associated with that gene in the second file, 
(3) Create a new file or R object, where each item contains the gene and all associated pathways.

I assume that the number of pathways per gene varies. As such, you probably want to store the results of your search function in a list object. Also, I don't think there are any matches in the data sample you provided. I replaced a few entries in the pathways file with 'Solyc07g064990' to illustrate.

```
# GENE LOOKUP

# load data
# genes is loaded as vector to reduce clutter below
genes <- read.csv('genes.csv', header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)[,1]
pathways <- read.csv('pathways.csv', header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

# create empty list to store gene/pathway matches
compiled <- list()

# loop through genes
for(i in genes)
{
      # store matching indices from pathways table
      matches <- grep(i,pathways[,1])
      # create new entry in 'compiled', giving it the current gene name (i)
      compiled[[i]] <- pathways[matches,2]
}
```

Also stuck this on github if you want to grab the sample data.
https://github.com/brlancer/stackex/tree/master/gene%20var%20lookup

First time contributing to Stack Overflow btw. Feedback welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my `dplyr` attempt (I'm on the process of learning dplyr, so any feedback to simplify is highly appreciated):

```
# Create some dummy data
dat <- data.frame(gene = c(rep("a", 2), "b", rep("c", 2)),path = paste("path", 1:5))

# Load dplyr

library(dplyr)    

dat %>% 
  group_by(gene) %>% 
  mutate(newpath=paste(.$path,collapse=", ")) %>% 
  distinct(gene) %>% 
  select(gene,newpath) %>%
  filter(gene %in% a$ID)
```

`group_by` does exactly that: groups by `gene`; then a new column is added (`mutate` which has a string made of the concatenation of all `path`s for each gene. There will be duplicated entries, so we need to keep `distinct` records. Last, we drop the initial `path` variable, as it's not needed any longer.

Result (for dummy data) looks like:

```
Source: local data table [3 x 2]

    gene        newpath
  (fctr)          (chr)
1      a path 1, path 2
2      a path 1, path 2
3      b         path 3
```

**####### EDIT TO ADD #######**

I was missing your request to see only those genes contained in your `a` data frame. To do that, please check the revised code (last line: `filter`).

for a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dat[,newpath:=paste(path,collapse=", "),by=gene][!duplicated(gene)][gene %in% a$ID]
```

In the first of the chained commands, we are creating the new variable `newpath` with the concatenated paths, obviously grouped by `gene`. In the second "box" we are stating that we don't want duplicated records of gene. The last one filters only those genes in `a$ID`.